# JSF view for external resource

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a multiple JSF projects (Modules) for a web-system and all of them share a core.
The core share some resources and one of the is the home page.
The home page is in this path:

```
core/
     META-INF/
              faces-config.xhtml (blank)
              resources/
                        view/
                             principal.xhtml
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
http://modulea/view/principal.jsf

http://moduleb/view/principal.jsf
```

But i get:
    The requested resource (/ModuleA/view/xhtml/principal.jsp) is not available.

I'd appreciate any ideas.

Comment: The URI in the error message doesn't match the request URIs. Haven't you oversimplified the request URIs? Anyway, this suggests that your main app is using JSP as default view technology. How did you configure it all?

Comment: BalusC, my main app it's not configured to use any web Technology because it's a core of classes used in other modules and i want to put shared xhtml too.
I need to configure as a wEB PROJECT?